# Corechart instead of LineChart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am using Google Visualization Chart with data from a Google sheet document.

It's working well. But I want to change LineChart to Chart Area, I got an error : Invalid visualization type: corechart. I tried it with other example but the corechart doesn't seem to be compatible with the datawrapper.

I tried this : https://jsfiddle.net/pvcb8gnw/

```
    ChartWrapper({ <- Replaced by ChartArea doesn't work
    chartType: 'LineChart',  <- Replaced by Corechart give the error
    chartType: 'LineChart',  <- Replaced by Areachart give the error
```

I am trying to do this : https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace...

```
chartType: 'LineChart'
```

with...

```
chartType: 'AreaChart'
```

Comment: I got the same : Invalid visualization type: areachart

Comment: `AreaChart` not `ChartArea` @user1708580, yes?